# Как спарсить названия карточек товара из интернет-магазина

Tags: python, requests, requests-html

Мне нужно спарсить названия всех книг на странице https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/actions/4379/
можно и одну, остальные я бы достал через цикл

Использую библиотеку `requests_html`
Открываю на странице код элемента, выбираю там нужный мне элемент (название какой-нибудь книги) и копирую селектор

Например для второй книги на странице - "Институт" у меня получается вот что - `body > div.page-wrap > main > div > section.event-cards > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.product-card__info > a > div.product-card__title.js-analytic-product-title`

Затем вставляю этот путь в следующий код:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/actions/4379/')
info = r.html.find('body > div.page-wrap > main > div > section.event-cards > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.product-card__info > a > div.product-card__title.js-analytic-product-title', first=True)
extracted_text = info.text
​
info.text
```

Получаю объект типа None и как следствие ошибку при попытке вытащить из него текст

Что я делаю неправильно, и может есть способ получше решить мою задачу?

Comment: А вы посмотрите `r.content`, что там. Там есть такое: `Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 418000140212848359-909244374727132046` Я так понимаю `Incapsula` это какая-то защита что ли, надо с ней разбираться.

Comment: Может нужен selenium, а может достаточно хоть какие-то хедеры передать вроде user-agent - надо пробовать.